# Sum product costs with same ID in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have multiple rows with same ID but different products/prices. I would like to get this in Power Query (PowerBI) due to the automation.

Excel formula looks like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2;$B$2:$B$7))
```

And the table is:

| A (ID) | B (price) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 |

My goal is to get this:

| C (Formula-price) |
| --- |
| 35 |
| 35 |
| 35 |
| 10 |
| 10 |
| 10 |

This step represent Column P & Q (Claims List) in this sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_nl2_Dgam7JDdyzX-urrO2AEXuCzhQkB1nogTLn2eA/edit#gid=0

Comment: Why would you like to repeat the result resp. the sum as often as the occurences of the ID? Otherwise you only need to group by the ID

Comment: I work with warranty cases, where there is only 1 responsible part of the whole job-cost. Thereafter I will use an if-formula to extract the total cost of the prices. I tried "group by" ID, but I lost all other essential data. This is my end goal where these steps counts as column P to Q: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_nl2_Dgam7JDdyzX-urrO2AEXuCzhQkB1nogTLn2eA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand. Please clarify and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Not sure how to specify it more, what part could be more clarified? 

Fictitious example, you've sold a desktop computer. Inside it you have CPU, Motherboard, PSU, GPU. The PSU short circuits, Motherboard and PSU breaks down too. The supplier of PSU will be responsible for the repair cost + the components that broke down (PSU, Motherboard, CPU). It all should be invoiced to this supplier. 

The ID is the warranty case number, price is the components price that were damaged.

Comment: Ok, I'll post an answer. We'll see if  I got you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am guessing a little bit but I think you would like to add the sum of B(price) grouped by A(id) to every row in your table. And you would like to use Powerquery for that.

First step would be to import the table into powerquery, then I duplicate the query and group it by ID. The third step is to merge these table by ID

**Step 1**
I took the following example data

[image]

Goto Data/From Table/Range and you should get

[image]

**Step2** Right click on the query above and select Duplicate

[image]

I named the result *sumTbl* ,  grouped it by ID and with price as the column to sum
[image]

***PS*** In the above step you can change to Advanced and add a second aggreagtion level and then expand. No need to merge!

The result looks like

[image]

**Step 3** Now you merge both tables. I merged them as a new one

[image]

The result is

[image]

Now you only need to expand the column sumTbl

[image]

The result will be

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you, fixed my problem and saved me from a lot of headaches! Cheers man, thank you for the solution :D

Answer (score 3):

In powerquery, right click and group on ID.  Add a sum of one of the number columns and then below that, choose All rows as the operation.

[image]

After grouping use arrows atop the new column to expand the other columns

Sample, without the expansion

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}, {"Column3", Int64.Type}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Column1"}, {{"Count", each List.Sum([Column2]), type nullable number}, {"data", each _, type table }})
 in  #"Grouped Rows"
```

Comment: Ah, yes, right, you can add two aggregations. Good catch.